# Difference between base.i, this.i and object.i in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

There are two clarifications I need which I am trying to understand.

I see that, I can access the variable "i" using "base" keyword as well as using the object. Is there any difference of it? I think, creation of object is memory consuming and hence we use base keyword itself to call base class members in derived class?

When to use this.i and base .i and object.i?

```
class Program
{
       public Program()
       {
           i = 20;
       }
    public readonly int i = 10;
}

class C : Program
{
    public C() : base()
    {
        //base.i = 20;
    }
    public int i = 20;
    public void Display()
    {
        C c = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(base.i);//prints 20
        Console.WriteLine(c.i);//prints 20
        Console.WriteLine(this.i); //Also prints 20 :D
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I tried to accept one answer as that helped me understand few things. But still, my question "the difference ans usage of 3 different styles at my context and in other contexts" is not clear. So please care to share your thoughts on this, I would appreciate it. I am sure there are millions like me who try to understand this :)

Comment: Microsoft have very nice documentation for all `keywords` in c#. It is just a quick google away. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hfw7t1ce.aspx

Comment: Close Voter - Could you please write the exact difference that you know and the best practice usage on 3 different options in this scenario and as well as all possible scenarios and close :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 1) You can use both to access the property as the sub class has extended it. There will only be a difference if you override that in the sub class or if you decide to create  a field with the same name in your sub class.

EDIT:

To override it, you can make it a `virtual` property in the base class

```
    public class Base
{
    public virtual int i {get; set;}
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    public override int i { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem 2 : Your StackOverflow**

you care creating a new instance of `Program` every time you create a new instance of `Program` it seems to be an infinite loop.

```
class Program 
{ 
    Program p = new Program(); // <-- this line here
```

Comment: how to override that in subclass

Comment: @Divine it needs to be marked as `virtual` in the base class and then in the subclass you mark it with `override`

Comment: Could you please show me how do you override for this i variable?

Comment: @Divine I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is **no** difference. Difference comes when you have field with same name in base class and derived class(typically we don't have it).

```
class Program
{
    public int i = 10;
}
class C : Program
{
    public int i = 20;
    public void Display()
    {
        C c = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(base.i);//prints 10
        Console.WriteLine(c.i);//prints 20
    }
}
```

`base` keyword refers to base class, so `base.i` refers to "member named i" in base class.

Also worth noting that when you access a member with base keyword and it doesn't exist compiler will produce an error.

```
class Program
{
    //public int i = 10; //No field named i
}
class C : Program
{
    public int i = 20;
    public void Display()
    {
        C c = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(base.i);//Compile time error here
        Console.WriteLine(c.i);//this refers to C.i field
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that I cannot use c.i and print 10? Are you sure?

Comment: @Divine Where did I state you cannot use `c.i` ?

Comment: You don't know. You have modified your comment. Well, I did not get compile time error, it works fine, it prints 20. Also, I have asked for "this.i" difference.

Comment: it prints 20 now. You said it will print only 10. class Program
{
       public Program()
       {
           i = 20;
       }
    public readonly int i = 10;
}
class C : Program
{
    public C() : base()
    {
        //base.i = 20;
    }
    public int i = 20;
    public void Display()
    {
        C c = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(base.i);//prints 10
        Console.WriteLine(c.i);//prints 20
        Console.WriteLine(this.i);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

Comment: @Divine Read my answer second part again. I have commented `i` in program class. You'll get a compile time error. and `this.i` is just calling `i`. it refers to `i` field of current class if any, if not it checks the parent class and so forth

Comment: Please run my code above, you will not get compile time error. I just ran successfully. I got 20 20 20 output. First - No compile time error. Second - i doesn't print 10 but 20. Third - My actually question  about difference between base.i and object.i you haven't understood. I expect some folks from other part can help us understand it better the exact difference and the usage.

Comment: @Divine I didn't say your code will result in compile time error. my code in second part will result in compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Question 1**

`Base` you can use when you want to refer you prent class from the child class.

Example :

```
public class A
{
  public int i {get;set;}
}

public class B:A
{
   publi void readvalueofi()
   {  Console.Writeln(base.i); }
}
```

This also useful when you override method of parent and want to call parent method from child

Example :

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Child");
    }
}
```

**Answer for Question 2 :
Reason for StackOverflow Exception**

You're creating an private instance of Program when Program is created so this is sort of an endless loop:

your first create Program instance. When this instance is creating it creates a new instance of Program. This instance also creates an instance of Programand again, and again etc.

So basially it creates infinite loop over here.

Comment: that who did -1 might have reason for this if dont than next time onwards do do -1